# Why my brand new laptop's hard drive came encrypted by BitLocker but does not display a padlock in the drive's icon?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, windows-11

My laptop's C drive's icon came out of the box looking like this (please disregard the drive size -- as I have played with the partition size)

[image]

From Windows Disk Management (shown in the image below), I see that the drive is BitLocker Encrypted. Yet, at this time, there is no padlock on the drive's icon (shown in the image above).

[image]

I've since installed some essential productivity software I needed for work (ie. Office, Chrome etc). This morning, I discovered that my C drive's icon has a padlock on it (shown in the image below)

[image]

Clearly my hard drive was BitLocker Encrypted at open-box (as shown in the Disk Management screenshot) What software added a padlock to my C drive? Why is it that I have a padlock now but not at the beginning?

I've never encountered encryption on my hard drive in the past. I researched a bit on the web. Most sites say I have an option to disable BitLocker if I right-click on the drive (shown in the image below)

[image]

But when I right-click on my drive, I don't have any BitLocker options (shown below)

[image]

Just curious... is the BitLocker encryption going to cause errors when I try to divide the whole hard drive into smaller partitions?

**UPDATE:**
I've included manage-bde -protectors -get C: results

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have your recovery key. You can get it with **managebde -protectors -get C:** See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/manage-bde-protectors You can also use **managebde** to check status etc.

Comment: We need you to provide the information from that command in order to help you

Comment: @Ramhound I've added the results

Comment: @spacenet - Are you looking to disable BitLocker protection?  Your security key is stored in the TPM.  If you don't already have the recovery password I would avoid making any system configuration changes.

Comment: What brand/model laptop is that? So that I know what to avoid buying...

Comment: @Ramhound Do I need to blur out the password in my screenshot above?

Comment: @spacenet - There are hundreds of millions of devices using BitLocker.  A malicious user would have to have access to your machine to use the password.  It appears that BitLocker protection is suspended, which is the reason the padlock, is "an unlocked padlock" version a "locked padlock".  Run `manage-bde –status C:` to determine if if BitLocker protection is suspended.

Comment: @Tonny I have a HP Envy. What's so bad about this set up that makes you want to avoid buying the brand?

Comment: @spacenet, HP is no different from any other OEM like Dell etc. Bitlocker is enabled suspended on compatible hardware and turned on if you use a MS account. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-bitlocker#bitlocker-automatic-device-encryption What makes it unclear is they don't seem to inform you or prompt you to save recovery key. Still you now have this so no need to worry. I don't believe you have to decrypt to shrink your partition but I've not done it for a while.